# RethinkDB insert and conflict resolution function syntax

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I'm trying to learn how to use the lambda function to resolve conflicts when inserting into a table with `rethinkdb` and `python`, like the last example on this [page](https://rethinkdb.com/api/python/insert/). I would like to compare a `timestamp` field between the `old_doc` and `new_doc` and keep the more recent document.

````
r.table(import_table).insert(documents, conflict=lambda id, old_doc, new_doc: new_doc if new_doc['timestamp'] > old_doc['timestamp'] else old_doc).run()```
````

This gives the following error

> rethinkdb.errors.ReqlQueryLogicError: Expected type DATUM but found
>   FUNCTION

I can't find much documentation on this error or using lambda functions for conflict resolution. Running something simpler like:

```
r.table(import_table).insert(documents, conflict=lambda id, old_doc, new_doc: new_doc).run()
```

gives the same error which makes me think that I'm not writing this correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are just looking for `r.branch`

```
r.table(import_table).insert(
    documents,
    conflict=lambda id, old_doc, new_doc: r.branch(
        new_doc['timestamp'] > old_doc['timestamp'],
        new_doc,
        old_doc
    )     
).run()
```

In cased of conflict, `insert` expects a datum, you were just returning a function (lambda). Here, the conflict resolution lambda will return the result of the `r.branch` comparison, which will be a datum this time.

EDIT:

I just tries it in the data explorer, in javascript, and it works for me:

```
r.table('foo').insert(
  [{id: 0, a: 3}, {id: 1, a: 2}],
  {
    conflict: function(id, old_doc, new_doc){
    return r.branch(
      old_doc('a').lt(new_doc('a')),
      new_doc,
      old_doc
    )}
  })
```

It seems to be the same than the python syntax I gave above, no?

Comment: I just pasted your example exactly into the data explorer and it returned the same error as above.

Answer (score 1):

Conflict function for inserting was implemented in rethinkdb 2.3.0 so this works after updating to that version or newer.